# Determining whether a matrix is unitary when given its eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal

Let L= $e^{\frac{2i \pi}{3}}$ and A $\in$ $M_{3,3}(\mathbb C)$ be a matrix with the following eigenspaces: $E_{1} = \mathbb C(1,-1,0)^T, E_{L}=\mathbb C(1,1,i)^T, E_{L^2}=\mathbb C(1,1,-2i)^T$. Is the matrix unitary? Justify your answer fully

**Observations** The only I know of showing that a matrix is unitary is by showing that all the columns are orthonormal. So I'm thinking about trying to extract information about the actual columns of the matrix A. But I'm not entirely sure about how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not unitary. If it was, it would have an orthonormal basis such that each of its elements is an eigenvector. But the basis that you provided is not orthogonal and, since we are in a $3$-dimensional space, every basis of eigenvectors can be obtained from the basis that you've provided simply by multiplying each of its elements by a scalar.

Comment: Ah I see! The flaw in my thought process was that I literally never considered the possibility that the matrix wasn't actually unitary. Lesson learnt. Will select as best answer.

Comment: @Vectorcalc That's funny, because my first reaction consisted also in trying to prove that it was unitary.

Comment: Carlos Santos Yeah something about the question just makes you think of proving the (wrong) direction first.